# How do I get rid of com.android.Pet.mediaproxy?

Tags: applications, 6.0-marshmallow, malware, system, system-apps

I found this on my phone on my Files after I woke up. I accidentally fell asleep and I have a housemate who likes messing with my things and decided to put something on my phone that is *actually* a malware that can be found in Chinese brand phones. Now, no matter what I do, it keeps returning even when I resetted it and the only solution I found is to flash a new rom or replace the rom/phone. Is there any way I could find it in the system and remove it? I can't find it in the "Apps" or "System" only apps.

One thing that I also want to know is, what exactly is *this*? I suspect that this is an old malware, just changed its name so that there wouldn't be much information about it (I suspect its old name is "com.android.snap" since it shows up in the search result). My phone is rather unknown in other countries but its legit enough aside from a occasional adware.

EDIT: What I meant by "resetted", I meant that I did a factory reset on my phone but the file keeps coming back. It's not an app for me since I can't find it anywhere in the Apps. Even if I turned off the WIFI, when I delete it, it keeps coming back on its own.

Comment: Even if your phone's brand is not well known, still edit your post and add it. If as you said it keeps coming back, then it means it's a system app & you can only remove it if your phone is rooted. If your phone is not rooted, did your friend root it?

Comment: It is best if you recreate your account or ask Stack Exchange to help regain access to this post (use Contact link at the bottom of this page). Anonymous edits can't be a substitute for exchange of comments.